# SQL INSERT issues after implementing BeginTransaction

Tags: sql, transactions, pdo

I have a few SQL queries on my php site that I execute one after another.

I thought of implementing transactions as if one fails then don't continue inserting the rest.

However after implementing transaction into my code I find that insertions are no longer happening.

Could anyone point out where I'm going wrong and how I can fix the problem that I am facing?

```
        $db = getConnection();

        try{
            /* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
            $db->beginTransaction();

            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Orders VALUES(\'\', :ref, :date, :aid, 1)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':ref', $referenceCode);
            $stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
            $stmt->bindParam(':aid', $agentId);
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE Agents SET Agent_OrderCount = :cow WHERE Agent_Id = :aid');
            $stmt->bindParam(':cow', $counter);
            $stmt->bindParam(':aid', $agentId);
            $stmt->execute();

            $db->commit();                  
            sendResponse(200, '{"Error":"0", "Message":"Successfully created order"}');
                return;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
        /* Recognize mistake and roll back changes */
            $db->rollBack();
            sendResponse(400, '{"Error":"3002", "Message":"'. $e->getMessage() .'"}');
            return;
        }
```

Prior to inserting the transaction code, I can assure you that all insert queries were working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could anyone point out where I'm going wrong

Sure.
You re asking this question on Stackoverflow instead of asking your server.
Have this attribute set after creating PDO connection

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

and then run your code again

Humans aren't intended to run code. Yes, we can spot some mistake. But there is one problem: there can be no errors in the code you posted, but somewhere else. So, just watching the code makes little sense. Code have to be run. And error reporting have to be set up. So, you own server will tell you what's going wrong, and this help will be way more reliable than just from some person who take a moment to digest your code.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I will make the changes now.
In the mean time Could you tell me what you mean by I should be asking the server instead of here in stackoverflow?